# Angular: How to determine which control was clicked

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am still learning the ins/outs of Angular coding.

I have 2 datePicker fields.  I thought the "#" was the id for the element.  Then I started to debug and found out that wasn't the case.

So my question is:  In the angular world how should I go about determining which element was clicked in my dateChanged event?

If you see I added the id to each input tag and that seems to work.  However ss this the appropriate way to handle this or can this be done with the ViewChild? (Seems like overkill that I have to set the Id and the # in order to do different types of operations.)

HTML:

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <input id="test2" #toInput matInput [matDatepicker]="toDatePicker" placeholder="To Date"
           (dateChange)="dateChanged($event)" disabled>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="toDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #toDatePicker disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Typescript:

```
  @ViewChild('fromInput', { read: MatInput }) fromInput: MatInput;
  @ViewChild('toInput', { read: MatInput }) toInput: MatInput;

  dateChanged(event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
    console.log("ID: " + event.targetElement.id);            
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#` character is used to define template variables. You can read more about this syntax [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-). It has nothing to do with css ids.

We need to define this variable to query for the element with the `@ViewChild` decorator. It does not accept css selectors as an argument. Only template reference variables or class tokens.

**component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input #toInput matInput (dateChange)="onToInputChange($event)" disabled>
 </mat-form-field>
 <mat-form-field>
    <input #fromInput matInput (dateChange)="onFromInputChange($event)" disabled>
 </mat-form-field>
```

**component.ts**

```
onFromInputChange() {
 // do something
}

onToInputChange() {
 // do something
}
```